# Delete Flatpak VLC Icons

Tags: 18.04, unity

[image]after trying Flatpak as app manager and installing VLC for trial, once deleted there are two icons of the same program on the ubuntu dashboard and I can't delete them. Would you please help me take them out? Where should I go to permanently cancel them?

Comment: This problem happens on ubuntu 18.04 lts with unity desktop ...

Comment: Which exactly icons?

Comment: the same icons as in vlc

Comment: Please add output of `snap list | grep -i vlc; flatpak list | grep -i vlc` and `find ~ -name '*vlc*.desktop'  2> /dev/null` to the question.

Comment: I understand little of what you said. Do I have to copy this path in full on the terminal? Thanks

Comment: Please execute all commands from previous comment and then paste their output to the question body by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1355222/edit).

Comment: Hi I copied the path you suggested on the terminal, but the two non-working icons of VLC are still there...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128108/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-francesco-aloisio).

Answer (score 0):

To remove all possible installations of VLC - both FlatPak and Snap use commands below:

```
flatpak remove org.videolan.VLC.Plugin.makemkv org.videolan.VLC.Plugin.bdj org.videolan.VLC org.videolan.VLC.Plugin.fdkaac
snap remove vlc
```

If desktop-files remain, then search for them using commands below:

```
find ~ -name '*vlc*.desktop' 2> /dev/null
grep -riE "vlc|videolan" --include=*.desktop ~ 2> /dev/null
```

and manually remove found files. In your case - the exact command would be:

```
rm -v /home/francesco/.local/share/applications/.desktop /home/francesco/.local/share/applications/vlc.desktop
```

Comment: You are a great Norbert! :D